# Use git OAuth token to clone the Repo

Tags: git, go, oauth-2.0

I am cloning public gitrepo with given golang code: (which works fine)

```
_, err = git.PlainClone(projectRoot, false, &git.CloneOptions{
    URL:      e.Repo,
    Progress: os.Stdout,
})
```

For the private git repo, I am generating an OAuth token and the code given below:

```
_, err = git.PlainClone(projectRoot, false, &git.CloneOptions{
    Auth:     &gitHttp.TokenAuth{Token: <oauth-token>},
    URL:      e.Repo,
    Progress: os.Stdout,
})
```

This is giving me something like :

```
unexpected client error: unexpected requesting "https://github.com/.../info/refs?service=git-upload-pack" status code: 400
```

I am using these particular modules

```
git "github.com/go-git/go-git/v5"
gitHttp "github.com/go-git/go-git/v5/plumbing/transport/http"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
_, err = git.PlainClone(projectRoot, false, &git.CloneOptions{
    Auth:     &gitHttp.BasicAuth{Username: <username>, Password: <oauth-token>},
    URL:      e.Repo,
    Progress: os.Stdout,
})
```